# How to echo every values in multi dimensional array using php?

Tags: php, arrays

How can this be done?

I want to echo each values in a multidimensional array.

Here is the print_r of my array.

```
Array ( [7] => Array ( [sale] => 08 [not_sale] => 00 [inventory] => -- [not_inventory] => -- ) [1] => Array ( [inventory] => 17 [not_inventory] => 00 [sale] => 08 [not_sale] => 00 ) [2] => Array ( [inventory] => 17 [not_inventory] => 00 [sale] => 08 [not_sale] => 00 ) [3] => Array ( [inventory] => 17 [not_inventory] => 00 [sale] => 08 [not_sale] => 00 ) [4] => Array ( [inventory] => 17 [not_inventory] => 00 [sale] => 08 [not_sale] => 00 ) [5] => Array ( [inventory] => 17 [not_inventory] => 00 [sale] => -- [not_sale] => -- ) [6] => Array ( [inventory] => -- [not_inventory] => -- [sale] => -- [not_sale] => -- ) )
```

i want to echo each item in each array...

here is my code. but no luck! Please respect

```
for($row=0; $row<7; $row++) {
    for($col=0; $col<7; $col++) {
        echo $myArray[$row][$col] . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) control structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach`

```
foreach($myArray as $subArray) {
    foreach($subArray as $key => $val) {
        echo $key . " - " . $val . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach ($arrRows as $arrSingleRow)
{
    echo "Sale         : " . $arrSingleRow["sale"];
    echo "Not Sale     : " . $arrSingleRow["not_sale"];
    echo "Inventory    : " . $arrSingleRow["inventory"];
    echo"<br/>==========================<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function should achieve what you're after. If you're purely after a list of the values (keys don't matter) try something like...

```
function list_array_values_recursive($array) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            list_array_values_recursive($value);
        }
        else {
            echo $value;
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Then just put your array into the function for the values to be echoed,

```
list_array_values_recursive($your_array);
```